# Why libonload.so without interp section is executable？

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I know libc.so is executeable because:

1. libc.so has a entry point function.
2. There is .interp section in libc.so.

And I refered many documents, .interp section is considered to be necessary for an executable so.
When I use call libonload.so, I can execute libonload.so, but readelf shows no .interp section.
I don't know how it works.
I run libonload.so, the result is:

```
[root@localhost onload-7.1.1.75]# /usr/lib64/libonload.so 
Onload 7.1.1.75
Copyright 2019-2021 Xilinx, 2006-2019 Solarflare Communications, 2002-2005 Level 5 Networks
Built: Mar  4 2024 15:49:30 (release)
Build profile header: <ci/internal/transport_config_opt_extra.h>
```

readelf -l /usr/lib64/libonload.so:

```
[root@localhost onload-7.1.1.75]# readelf -l /usr/lib64/libonload.so 

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0xa2e0
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000a5ff0 0x00000000000a5ff0  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x00000000000a6818 0x00000000002a6818 0x00000000002a6818
                 0x0000000000002770 0x0000000000003060  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x00000000000a6d90 0x00000000002a6d90 0x00000000002a6d90
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200
                 0x0000000000000024 0x0000000000000024  R      4
  TLS            0x00000000000a6818 0x00000000002a6818 0x00000000002a6818
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000bec  R      8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000094684 0x0000000000094684 0x0000000000094684
                 0x000000000000245c 0x000000000000245c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x00000000000a6818 0x00000000002a6818 0x00000000002a6818
                 0x00000000000007e8 0x00000000000007e8  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .plt .text .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   01     .init_array .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   02     .dynamic 
   03     .note.gnu.build-id 
   04     .tbss 
   05     .eh_frame_hdr 
   06     
   07     .init_array .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got
```

Btw, libonload.so is a driver for SolarFlare Nic.Source code can be got at [https://github.com/Xilinx-CNS/onload][1]
[1]: https://github.com/Xilinx-CNS/onload

I write a demo according to onload source:

```
#include <sys/uio.h>                                                                                                        
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int my_do_syscall3(int num, long a1, long a2, long a3)
{
  int rc;
  __asm__ __volatile__(

   "syscall"
   : "=a" (rc)
   : "0"((long)num), "D"(a1), "S"(a2), "d"(a3)
   : "r11","rcx","memory"

  );

  return rc;
}

#define my_syscall3(call, a1, a2, a3) \
        my_do_syscall3(__NR_##call, (a1), (a2), (a3))
extern "C" int func()
{
        struct iovec v[1];
        static const char msg0[] = "Hello so\n";

        v[0].iov_base = (void*) msg0;
        v[0].iov_len  = sizeof(msg0)-1;

        my_syscall3(writev, STDOUT_FILENO, (long) v, 1);
        my_syscall3(exit, 0, 0, 0);

        return 0;
}
```

My build command is :

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -e func test.cpp -o libtest.so
```

I execute ./libtest.so, resulting in segmention faults.
Then I add .interp section in test.cpp:

```
extern const char elf_interpreter[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";
```

And compile and execute again.It runs well as expected.

At last, I do it successfully.Adding `static` to my_do_syscall3 and it can work without an interpreter.

Comment: It just uses `-e` in https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/aff60a36ed3543446d9ff179905f47c47d1e300b/src/lib/transport/unix/mmake.mk#L85 .  `I refered many documents, .interp section is considered to be necessary for an executable so` Then how does interpreter executes `/usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`? With interp to itself? There are _a lot_ of libraries without interp. `I refered many documents, .interp section is considered to be necessary for an executable so` Please _post_ the links to the documents. What documents exactly?

Comment: `not working as expected` Then `dbg` and `strace` are friends to look for. I would guess something with initialization of stack or smth.

Comment: I am still stuck in this problem. I find no way to debug it. I try gdb. But as running it, it crash.And I use gdb to load core file, expecting to watch call stack. And the stack only shows address, just like `#0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffb77db5f0 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`.  I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interp is (only) needed if you want an interpreter to run, like glibc or musl. You can hardcode syscalls and do all the stuff yourself without an `ld.so` interpreter, see `man ld.so`. It has nothing to do with shared library vs executable. Actually, any ELF executable is a shared library, any shared library can be an executable, it's all ELF format.

> Why libonload.so without interp section is executable?

Because it was built that way. See https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/aff60a36ed3543446d9ff179905f47c47d1e300b/src/lib/transport/unix/mmake.mk#L85 and `man ld`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588240/what-mandates-the-start-entrypoint-kernel-ld-linux-so-etc and the linked articles https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/ and https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/ . See `man elf` documentation on `e_entry`.

---

There are a lot of executables and libraries without interp on my system:

```
$ f() { if a=$(readelf -l "$1" 2>/dev/null) && ! <<<"$a" grep -q interp; then echo $1; fi; }; export -f f; printf "%s\n" /bin/* /usr/lib/*.so | xargs -P20 -n1 bash -c 'f "$1"' --
/bin/busybox
/bin/catatonit
/bin/containerd-shim
/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v1
/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2
/bin/docker-init
/bin/qemu-*-static
...
$ f() { if a=$(readelf -l "$1" 2>/dev/null) && ! <<<"$a" grep -q interp; then echo $1; fi; }; export -f f; printf "%s\n" /bin/* /usr/lib/*.so | xargs -P20 -n1 bash -c 'f "$1"' -- | wc -l
3099
```

Comment: I write a demo and do a test, but it is not working as expected. I added test part at the end of my question. Do you have any idea?